# Definition of entropy in the canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am currently following an introductory class on statistical mechanics. This course starts with general notions of statistics (as a reminder), goes over explaining why one would want a statistical description of the world by taking a look into the classical and quantum cases. Based on these various examples, the course starts rather classically by introducing the **micro-canonical ensemble**. There, one defines entropy as

$S = -k_BT\log\Omega$

Further down the book students are introduced with the **canonical ensemble**. Entropy is defined in this new ensemble as

$S = -k_B \Sigma_{n,j} P_{n,j}\log P_{nj}$

The author kickstarts the proof of this statement with the following line:

$S = k_B\log Z + \frac{k_BT}{Z}\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N_1,...,N_C}$

where $c$ is the number of different particle species in the system.

The proof goes on from there as follows:

$S = k_B\log Z + \frac{k_BT}{Z}\Sigma_{n,j}\frac{E_n}{k_BT^2}e^{-\frac{E_n}{k_BT}} = k_B\log Z - k_B\Sigma_{n,j}P_{n,j}\log\left(P_{n,j}Z\right)$

My question lies on the first line of the proof. **Why is it valid that the author can kickstart the proof with the line hereabove?**

Let me conclude this question by wishing a wonderful 2024 to whomever is reading this. Cheers!

Comment: I cannot follow the argument. The Gibbs-Shannon entropy is defined as in your second equation. Maximizing it under various constraints gives the well-known probabilities and equations for entropy. BTW: You should always number your equations. Also use $$ environment for in-line math.

Comment: When "entropy is defined", there is nothing to prove, it's a definition. Actually that formula defines information entropy of a probability distribution. Showing that its value for canonical distribution is or corresponds to thermodynamic entropy can be subject of a proof/disproof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author may have missed a few lines that define the canonical ensemble. In its essence, the canonical ensemble describes the thermodynamic potential $F = -k_B T lnZ$, and then already uses it to derive the entropy value $S = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in the canonical ensemble $p_k=\frac{E^{-\beta E_k}}{Z}$ where $Z=\sum_{m} e^{-\beta E_m}$, so the probability as the author defined it for the first time is

$ S=-k_{B}\sum_{k}\frac{E^{-\beta E_k}}{\sum_{m} e^{-\beta E_m}}\log{\frac{E^{-\beta E_k}}{\sum_{m} e^{-\beta E_m}}}=k_{B}\sum_{k}\frac{E^{-\beta E_k}}{\sum_{m} e^{-\beta E_m}}(\log{Z}-\log{e^{-\beta E_k}})
$$

$=k_{B}(\sum_{k}\frac{E^{-\beta E_k}}{Z}\log{Z}-\frac{E^{-\beta E_k}}{Z}\log{e^{-\beta E_k}})=k_{B}\frac{Z}{Z}\log{Z}-k_{B}\sum_{k}p_k E_k=K_B\log{Z}-\beta \langle E\rangle $$

this is more or less the way from probability to thermodinamic entropy